# For every positive even number $n$, does there always exist a pair of prime $(p,q)$ such that $p-q =n$?

Tags: prime-numbers

$$2 = 5-3 \\
4 = 7-3 \\
6 = 11-5 \\
8 = 19-11 \\
10 = 13-3 \\
\vdots$$

For every positive even number $n$, does there always exist a pair of prime $(p,q)$ such that $p-q =n$?

Comment: This is similar to the Goldbach conjecture and I would expect a similar situation.  I would be sure it is true but expect that there is no known proof.

Comment: @RossMillikan so are Schnizel's hypothesis, hypothesis $H_n$, Bertrand's postulate, Dickson's conjecture, Polignac's conjecture,  twin prime conjecture, etc.

Comment: equivalently this $$\forall m\in \mathbb{N};\exists(x,y)\in A:=\{(a,b):a-b=m\}:$$$$2\cdot a+1,2\cdot b+1\in\mathbb{P}$$